# How can I tell if a directory is mounted with noatime or nodirtime?

Tags: filesystems, mount, osx, atime

I work with an NFS partition on a mac. Commands like `du` take a very long time, and I was considering unmounting the NFS and remounting it with noatime and nodirtime. The partitions have been mounted since I started my job, so I don't know if the NFS partition is already mounted with noatime or nodirtime.

**How can I tell if a mount has noatime and/or nodirtime enabled?**

Answer (score 8):

To check which options a partition was mounted with, you can use the `mount -l` command. This will output a bunch of lines that look like this:

> sysfs on /sys type sysfs **(rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)**
>
> proc on /proc type proc **(rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)**

I've highlighted the part you should be looking at. Just check the line for the partition you're interested in to see if it says `noatime`/`nodirtime`.

Comment: Usually mount by itself is enough.

Comment: The OSX mount manual doesn't mention a `-l` flag. Is there a way to do this that works in OSX?

Comment: Dan - You should just be able to do `mount` by itself, and look at the part of the output I mentioned above. The `-l` flag just tells it to include labels, but isn't actually necessary for what you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using

```
mount
```

you might find additional information looking at the dmesg output.

Note however that you should expect no improvement when running **du** which will walk down within subdirectories and do a stat on each file (not like **df** which will return immediately)